# How to call custom function asynchronously using javascript?

Tags: javascript, angular, oojs

I am using one angular third party module in my application. That module is providing some call-back methods like login success, failure etc, and I am executing my custom scripts inside the call-back method.

But the issue here is I want to execute my custom script asynchronously which means the call-back should not wait until my custom script executes. Now if there is any issue in script their call-back is not completing and entire script is affecting due to this. So I want to call my custom method asynchronously from third party's call-back event.

I tried all the possible ways using the below example but nothing is working. I have used promises also but not working,

```
EV.Event.on('login.success', function (res) { //third party's callback
    try {
        custCallbackLoginSuccess(res); //my custom method
    } catch(Error) {
        console.log("error"+Error);
    }
});

async function custCallbackLoginSuccess(res) {
    var success = test; //here test is undefied. so 'login.success' -should not wait untill this execution completes. It should complete without any error
}
```

Answer (score 1):

since `custCallbackLoginSuccess` is an async function, your try-catch in `login.success` will not catch any error.

you have to write your code like this:

```js
EV.Event.on('login.success', function (res) { //third party's callback
     custCallbackLoginSuccess(res); //your custom method
});

async custCallbackLoginSuccess(res) {
    try {
        var success = test;
    } catch(Error) {
        console.log("error"+Error);
        // don't throw any error here if you don't want to disturb the caller
    }
}
```

if you need the result of `custCallbackLoginSuccess` in the `login.success`, you have no choice but to await to receive its result.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I tried the above, still 'login.success' is not completing. It is throwing the error

Comment: can you give me the error call stack? upload it somewhere perhaps